# How to pause a loop with a mouse click using pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, onmouseclick

I m a beginner in python and I m doing a project using pygame. I initiated a loop on a mouse click and it runs good. But i couldn't stop that loop. I want it to stop on a mouse click and the loop should run until that mouse click. I have provided the outline of the code, below. Can anyone help me with a proper code? Thanks in advance.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
         (mx,my)= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
         if((mx>=375)&(mx<=425)&(my>=500)&(my<=550)): #to begin loop on mouse click#
           while True:
              ---statements-----
              if((mx>=300)&(mx<=350)&(my>=500)&(my<=550)): #to end loop on mouse click#
                 exit
              else:
                 continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once you enter the *while True* loop, you are no longer waiting for mouse events coming from pygame. Try checking for new events right before looping:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if 375 <= mx <= 425 and 500 <= my <= 550:
        run = True
        while run:
            # statements
            # ...
            for event in pygame.event.get(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
                mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if 300 <= mx <= 350 and 500 <= my <= 550:
                    run = False
```

You can filter directly the events in the event.get call.

Note that I rewrote the boundary checks, as the logic and in Python is actualy *and*, while *&* is a bitwise operation. Python allows for a cool syntax when checking ranges too!

Comment: Thanks @jminuscula, But return should be used in a function. So it is better to use exit, or change the while condition to false.

Comment: yes, return would only work in a function. I've modified the code to make it clearer.